# Facebook Open Graph requiring URL to publish an action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

It looks like Facebook's Open Graph API requires a URL to publish an action. My confusion is that my workflow is the following:

- User invokes an action on an object in a native iOS application
- This event is sent to a private, server-side API
- There is no public URL to correlate to this event, only the mobile client can interact with the server API

How am I to publish to my timeline if Facebook is showing examples such as the following:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/recipebox:cook?
  recipe=http://www.example.com/pumpkinpie.html&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

My app has no http://www.example.com/pumpkinpie.html. I need to be able to post the Open Graph API from my server whenever an event is generated from the client to the server.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'd like to use Open Graph, but I don't have any server-side component at all, just a mobile app...

Answer (score 3):

You need a URL - even if when users land there all that happens is they're redirected elsewhere, you need a URL with the metadata that describes the object.

If the server doesn't have an URL which represents the object you're taking the action on, where would people interacting with that story on Facebook go?

Comment: Side note: there may be functionality to not require a URL for each object in the future, but currently each object needs a URL with the meta tags describing that object

Comment: @Igy Do you happen to know if there's been any change in this area? I'd just like to use Open Graph to post an achievement to a user's timeline from a mobile (Android) app which has no server-side component at all, so I'm at rather a loss when it comes to providing a URL. Thanks!

Comment: At the moment, no, I think it's a good use-case though, keep an eye on the developer blog - i'm pretty sure we'd announce it if we launch the ability to post OG actions without the URL requirement