# Publish an action without an external recipe webpage?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, action, recipe

I'm working on a project where we try not to use any server side languages.

Is it possible to publish an action without an external recipe webpage?

I see an example on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publish-action/

> FB.api('/me/recipebox:cook', 'post',    { recipe :
>   'http://www.example.com/pumpkinpie.html' });

but it requires a recipe from an external page.

Comment: Exactly duplicated and perfectly answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10558476/1515819

Answer (score 0):

You can publish the actions without server side languages. But what do you mean by the external page?

You just required to add the meta tags in the page where you are publishing the actions.

Comment: // I don't really want to use meta tags. My question is...why can't we just pass meta tag values using javascript?

Comment: Sorry but am afraid that you cant. Just go with what's in the tutorials :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the new object API, the objects will be hosted at Facebook.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/